# Highcharts pie on legenditemclick avoid slicing of pie but show animation on legend item

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts, legend

I am using highcharts to display pie with legends.

```
legendItemClick: function (e) {
return false;
}
```

I am using the above legendItemClick event which returns false to avoid the default behaviour. I would like to reduce the opacity of legendItem if the point is unselected and vice versa.

```
legendItemClick: function (e) {
if(!this.selected)
//reduce opacity of this.legendItem
else 
//set opacity back to 1 of this.legendItem
return false;
}
```

Added fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3vVGB/17/

I appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So generally you need to only modify legend item? what should happen with pie slice ?

Comment: Yes. i would do something else with the pie slice (like this.select()) other than the default behavior. Now i need to be able to modify only the legend item. Could you help me on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is this.legendItem.addClass() with which i can add a class containing the opacity style. But there is no removeClass method available for legendItem. :(

Comment: By select you mean sliced element or element with hola (shadow around slice? )

Comment: I meant the sliced element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3vVGB/17/  please find the fiddle link

Comment: Ok and what is wrong? Please desribe step by step what you need because it is still unclear.

Comment: i am currently hiding and showing the legenditems, instead i want to reduce and increase the opacity of the legenditems. Please find the comments in the fiddle.(line no 26 and 28 basically which i need to change)

Comment: And what should happend with slices, should have default behaviour or doing nothing?

Comment: I am cancelling the default behaviour. On legendItemClick, if ctrl key is pressed, i am selecting the particular slice without unselecting other slices. If ctrl key is not pressed, i am selecting only that particular slice which in turn unselects all other slices.(fiddle line no 14-22) Next, i am looping around each and every slice and if it is selected, then I NEED TO SET OPACITY OF THAT LEGENDITEM TO 1, else, I NEED TO REDUCE THE OPACITY OF THAT LEGENDITEM TO 0.5. Currently instead of reducing and increasing the opacity i am hiding and showing the legenditem. Hope now its clear. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

there is no removeClass method available for legendItem. But u can use "**attr**" method. Eg.: this.legendItem.attr("class","")